# pass only integer datatype as command line argument in c

Tags: c

I'm new to C programming. I've been practicing use of command line arguments in C. I've written a C code to calculate the area and circumference of a circle. This is my code:

```
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

float circle(float pi,int r)
{
    float cir;
    cir=(pi*r*r);
    printf("area of the circle is: %f \n",cir);
}
float circumference(float pi,int r)
{
    float circum;
    circum=(2*pi*r);
    printf("the circumference is: %f \n",circum);
}
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{   int r,r1;
    float pi;
    r=0;
    pi=M_PI;
    if(argc>3 || argc<3)
    {
        printf("error \n");
        exit(0);
    }
    r=atoi(argv[1]);
    r1=atoi(argv[2]);
    circle(pi,r);
    circumference(pi,r1);
}
```

My results are proper but I want to enhance my code to stop if the argument given is not a number. if not it should be an error. How can I do it? Any leads will be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: One possibility is to use `isdigit`.

Comment: Thank you for replying. How  can I use isdigit for multiple argument @1201ProgramAlarm

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `atoi` returns `0` if parsing fails, though 0 might be a valid input as well.

In C, I see two options to overcome this:

(1) use `sscanf` and see if exactly one number could be parsed:

```
if (sscanf(argv[1],"%d",&r) != 1) {
   // some error handling here...
}
```

(2) check if at least the first character is a digit (yielding a valid number then):

```
if (!isdigit(argv[1][0]) {
   // some error handling here...
}
```

But note that you may have to consider `-` or `+` and white spaces as well.

So I'd actually prefer option 1.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Both of those cases will accept the string `"3mice"` as the value `3`. That may or may not be good enough for your purpose.

Comment: thankyou for replying that made me think of a new test case @HAL9000

Comment: @HAL9000 That could be covered by checking `sscanf(argv[1],"%d %c",&r,&c) == 1` where `char c;` would be another variable to catch any unwanted characters coming *after* the number.